# Changing a folder to a One Note Document in CSOM for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I am trying to amend the Prog-ID on a Sharepoint folder so I can change it to a One note document.

Here is my code in CSOM, but it just says Prog-ID is read only, but I have read this can be done, any ideas ?

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = ""
$ListName=""
$FolderName=""
$UserName=""
$Password =""

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))


    #Set up the context
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
    $Context.Credentials = $credentials

    #Get the List Root Folder
    $ParentFolder=$Context.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($ListName)

    $folderCollection = $ParentFolder.Folders


    $Context.load($folderCollection)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()



    foreach($folder in $folderCollection)
    {
        $folder.ProgId = “SharePoint.DocumentSet”
        $folder.Update()


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this out, ProgId IS READ ONLY so I used HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type instead.. 
this is my sample code in CSOM.

```
Add-Type -Path “C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll”

Add-Type -Path “C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll”

Add-Type -Path “C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll”



# Specify tenant admin and site URL

$SiteUrl = ""


$UserName = ""

$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Password" -AsSecureString




$ClientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)

$ClientContext.Credentials = $credentials

$list = $ClientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('');


$ListItemCreationInformation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$ListItemCreationInformation.UnderlyingObjectType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileSystemObjectType]::Folder
$ListItemCreationInformation.LeafName = "Beans Meanz Heinz "
$ListItemCreationInformation.FolderUrl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
$listitem = $list.AddItem($ListItemCreationInformation)
$listitem["Title"] = "Beans Meanz Heinz"
$listitem["HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type"] = "OneNote.Notebook"


$listitem.Update();
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Hope this helps someone who is banging there head with this.